# Unable to negotiate a key exchange method with Mina deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ubuntu, deployment, ssh

I'm encountering a message like this while deploying with Mina, but not sure why Git is not able to pull the repo.

I've tried switching sshd_config due to `Unable to negotiate a key exchange method` message, but still can't figure things out. Thanks for helping.

```
   -----> Creating a temporary build path
          $ touch "deploy.lock"
          $ mkdir -p "$build_path"
          $ cd "$build_path"

   -----> Cloning the Git repository
          $ git clone "git@github.com:repo/project.git" "/home/deploy/project/scm" --bare
          Cloning into bare repository '/home/deploy/project/scm'...
          Unable to negotiate a key exchange method
          fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

          Please make sure you have the correct access rights
          and the repository exists.
    !     ERROR: Deploy failed.

   -----> Cleaning up build
          $ rm -rf "$build_path"
          Unlinking current
          $ rm -f "deploy.lock"
          OK

    !     Command failed.
          Failed with status 1 (19)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is, that your local SSH client and  the remote endpoint at GitHub are unable to agree on a common key exchange method.

This will mostly occur when you poked around with the set of available Key exchange methods or you are using a very old & outdated SSH client which does not support any method which is still regarded as safe.

Interestingly this only occurs on *some* GitHub Repos: I'm still able to pull from other reports.

To diagnose you can set the following environment variable to see more of the SSH output:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vv"
```

To fix it, I added a custom entry in my `config_ssh` or `~/.ssh/.config` allowing more legacy algorithms for that host. Please note this should appear **above** any `Host *` section:

```
# Github needs diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 some of the 
# time but not always.
Host github.com
    KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
```