# Suddenly can't push to heroku: "unable to negotiate key exchange method"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssl, heroku, ssh

"git push heroku" is suddenly failing. (I installed Node.js and I think it may have upgraded some things and broke this somehow.)

I've read all the similar posts; it's not telling me which exchange was 'offered', and everything looks like it matches, but the call fails and I'm at a loss.
I did heroku auth:login successfully.

`ssh git@heroku.com -v` gives me the following:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/jeff/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for * <This line is 'Host *'>
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.156] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/jeff/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/jeff/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jeff/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jeff/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version endosome
debug1: no match: endosome
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com none
Unable to negotiate a key exchange method
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I encountered same problem this morning.

I can avoid this problem, with change git remote url as below.

from:
git@heroku.com:app-name.git

to: 
https://git.heroku.com/app-name.git

you can use command below

`git remote rm heroku
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/app-name.git`

Comment: This fixed it! Everybody else is probably right as well. I think the actual problem was that I had it pointing to "git@heroku.bitbucket:<app-name.git>", which used to work. So my best guess is I had an old ssh which supported this syntax, then the (accidental) upgrade to the latest version broke it. Anyway it works now!

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem this morning. It was because I was using an outdated ssh client. I suspected that was the problem after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410640/unable-to-negotiate-a-key-exchange-method-with-mina-deployment). On my mac I use [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) so I was able to install openssh. For me it was just:
`brew install openssh`

Then `git push heroku master` was successful.

I'm not as familiar with Linux but I suspect you can use a package manager like [apt-get](https://wiki.debian.org/apt-get).

Comment: Right. It was the openssh version. Updated with `brew install openssh` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

They recently disabled some older insecure key exchange methods.  As Kalimar said, you are probably using an outdated ssh client.  If `brew install openssh` (or equivalent if you're on something other than a Mac) doesn't fix it, or you don't want to do that for whatever reason, another approach is to change the URL to use HTTPS transport.  The format is:

`https://git.heroku.com/YOUR-APP-NAME.git`

Answer (score 0):

First, double-check if the remote heroku is indeed an ssh URL

```
git remote -v
```

Then check the content of `C:/Users/jeff/.ssh/config` which should have an `heroku.com` entry, to get the actual private key path used.

If it is an https URL, check your `~/_netrc` file, as in "[Heroku CLI Authentication](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/authentication)".
But for ssh, see [Managing Your SSH Keys](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys), and what `heroku keys:add` returns.